# how to cancel a request safely?

Tags: ios, multithreading, upload, download

i want to know how to cancel a download or upload request safely?
we known we will always set several callback blocks(start block, progress block, failed/success/complete block) when we start a download request or upload request, and this request always run in a non main thread. but we could cancel request in a main thread.

we may hope it stop download/upload and don't callback anymore after we call cancel api.
we may also hope it stop download/upload and trigger callback function if we call cancel api.

so how to write the code to cancel a download/upload request safely? 
i'm really don't understand how to cancel a request safely?

because when you are doing an cancel operation, the code of the download/upload may run at the begin of a new slice data finished or is still doing download/upload data, the you can check whether it is cancelled if you prepare to download the next data, if cancelled, we callback failed block and return. if not, we continue a new slice data download/upload if needed.

also when you are doing an cancel operation, the code of the download/upload may be processing some logics, for example append/read new data, prepare call progress block....

so it let me feel hard to do to cancel appropriate.

could anybody tell me what's the true logic to do the cancel operation.

Comment: What are you using to start them / queue them ?
Did you consider using AFNetworking ? You have ready solutions there

Comment: i ever see the source code of AFNetwork, it do cancel by first set cancel flag to YES, then asynchronous call an real cancel operation with the same thread to download thread